# Obtener datos de dos tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy aprendiendo MySql y me estoy volviendo loco con las relaciones. No consigo, lo que yo considero que debería pasar, hacer una relación de **uno a uno** (no quiero pensar cuando tenga que hacer las de **uno a varios** o de **varios a varios**).
El ejercicio consiste en una tabla de Personas y otra tabla de Teléfonos. Si bien se podría solucionar con un campo extra en Personas para los teléfonos; la idea es hacer que el ejercicio funcione. He aquí los códigos:

```
create table personas (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    nombres varchar(20),
    apellidos varchar(20),
    tipo varchar(10)  /* si es persona física o jurídica*/
    );


create table telefonos (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    tipo varchar(15),  /* si es celular o teléfono de línea*/
    numero varchar(15),
    id_persona int,
    foreign key (id_persona) references personas(id)
    );
```

Aquí las tablas cargadas.

```
MariaDB [prueba_2]> select * from personas;
+----+---------------+-----------+--------+
| id | nombres       | apellidos | tipo   |
+----+---------------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | Juan Carlos   | Gutierrez | física |
|  2 | Susana María  | Sánchez   | Física |
|  3 | Adolfo Martín | Alonzo    | Física |
|  4 | Jimena Angel  | Tarico    | Física |
|  5 | Alicia Mónica | Oviedo    | Física |
+----+---------------+-----------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)


MariaDB [prueba_2]> select * from telefonos; 
+----+---------+-------------+------------+  
| id | tipo    | numero      | id_persona |  
+----+---------+-------------+------------+  
|  1 | Celular | 154 111 111 |          1 |  
|  2 | Celular | 154 222 222 |          2 |  
|  3 | Celular | 154 333 333 |          3 |  
|  4 | Celular | 154 444 444 |          4 |  
|  5 | Celular | 154 555 555 |          5 |  
+----+---------+-------------+------------+  
5 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Ahora bien. Según yo esto debería tirarme por cada persona un telefono. pero lo que me tira es:

```
MariaDB [prueba_2]> select * from personas, telefonos;
+----+---------------+-----------+--------+----+---------+-------------+------------+
| id | nombres       | apellidos | tipo   | id | tipo    | numero      | id_persona |
+----+---------------+-----------+--------+----+---------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | Juan Carlos   | Gutierrez | física |  1 | Celular | 154 111 111 |          1 |
|  2 | Susana María  | Sánchez   | Física |  1 | Celular | 154 111 111 |          1 |
|  3 | Adolfo Martín | Alonzo    | Física |  1 | Celular | 154 111 111 |          1 |
|  4 | Jimena Angel  | Tarico    | Física |  1 | Celular | 154 111 111 |          1 |
|  5 | Alicia Mónica | Oviedo    | Física |  1 | Celular | 154 111 111 |          1 |
|  1 | Juan Carlos   | Gutierrez | física |  2 | Celular | 154 222 222 |          2 |
|  2 | Susana María  | Sánchez   | Física |  2 | Celular | 154 222 222 |          2 |
|  3 | Adolfo Martín | Alonzo    | Física |  2 | Celular | 154 222 222 |          2 |
|  4 | Jimena Angel  | Tarico    | Física |  2 | Celular | 154 222 222 |          2 |
|  5 | Alicia Mónica | Oviedo    | Física |  2 | Celular | 154 222 222 |          2 |
|  1 | Juan Carlos   | Gutierrez | física |  3 | Celular | 154 333 333 |          3 |
|  2 | Susana María  | Sánchez   | Física |  3 | Celular | 154 333 333 |          3 |
|  3 | Adolfo Martín | Alonzo    | Física |  3 | Celular | 154 333 333 |          3 |
|  4 | Jimena Angel  | Tarico    | Física |  3 | Celular | 154 333 333 |          3 |
|  5 | Alicia Mónica | Oviedo    | Física |  3 | Celular | 154 333 333 |          3 |
|  1 | Juan Carlos   | Gutierrez | física |  4 | Celular | 154 444 444 |          4 |
|  2 | Susana María  | Sánchez   | Física |  4 | Celular | 154 444 444 |          4 |
|  3 | Adolfo Martín | Alonzo    | Física |  4 | Celular | 154 444 444 |          4 |
|  4 | Jimena Angel  | Tarico    | Física |  4 | Celular | 154 444 444 |          4 |
|  5 | Alicia Mónica | Oviedo    | Física |  4 | Celular | 154 444 444 |          4 |
|  1 | Juan Carlos   | Gutierrez | física |  5 | Celular | 154 555 555 |          5 |
|  2 | Susana María  | Sánchez   | Física |  5 | Celular | 154 555 555 |          5 |
|  3 | Adolfo Martín | Alonzo    | Física |  5 | Celular | 154 555 555 |          5 |
|  4 | Jimena Angel  | Tarico    | Física |  5 | Celular | 154 555 555 |          5 |
|  5 | Alicia Mónica | Oviedo    | Física |  5 | Celular | 154 555 555 |          5 |
+----+---------------+-----------+--------+----+---------+-------------+------------+
25 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Es evidente que hay algo muy importante que no he entendido, algo conceptual o algo en los comandos de consulta.

---

Yo pensé que con **sólo establecer la relación con freign key ya bastaba para que se asociaran ambas tablas**. Como pueden ver sólo son 5 registros en cada tabla y no se repiten; pero el Select me tira como 20 filas. O sea que si o sí, si quiero las 5 filas con el correspondiente telefono debo trabajar en el comando select. En eso consistía mi duda: **si con foreign key ya era suficiente** para que ambas tablas se unieran; por eso lo sintético de mi Select.
La duda que me queda ahora es **¿se puede prescindir las foreign key?** o ambas son necesarias: las foreign key y los joins en los selects.
Ahora me tengo que poner a estudiar los joins.
Espero haberme explicado. Gracias por responderme.

Comment: ¿Y cual es la intención de esta consulta `select * from personas, telefonos;`?, si nos explicas mejor el resultado que buscas tal vez te podamos ayudar a construir la consulta

Comment: Gracias por responder. Segun yo debería darme los nombres de las personas asociados a un telefono de la otra tabla. Sería de uno a uno.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El primer punto a mencionar es que así como esta la construcción de tus tablas el motor no sabrá que se trata propiamente de una relación **`1:1`** de hecho al momento es mas una relación **`1:N`**.

Lo anterior por que no esta declarada ninguna regla propiamente que le impida a la tabla **`telefonos`** recibir el **`id`** de la misma persona para otro teléfono.

Por lo anterior deberías hacer uso de [`UNIQUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) de esta forma:

```
id_persona int UNIQUE,
```

Ahora para la consulta debes  hacer un `JOIN` entre las 2 tablas de esta forma:

```
SELECT personas.nombres,
       personas.apellidos,
       personas.tipo,
       telefonos.tipo,
       telefonos.numero
FROM personas
JOIN telefonos ON personas.id = telefonos.id_persona;
```

Donde:

- Eliges las columas deseadas de ambas tablas
- Haces un [**`JOIN`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) para unir ambas indicando en el **`ON`** la búsqueda de la igualdad entre la llave primaria de **`personas`** y la llave foránea de la tabla de **`teléfonos`** las cuales sirven para unir e identificar registros asociados

Answer (score 0):

Probaste

```
SELECT p.nombres, 
       p.apellidos, 
       t.tipo, 
       t.numero
FROM personas p
INNER JOIN telefonos t ON p.id = t.id_persona
```

Comment: Recuerda explicar.

Comment: Es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta. Si bien ese código podría resolver el problema, es mejor incluir una explicación de cómo y por qué lo haría.

Answer (score 0):

Las *foreign key* son **restricciones**, también llamadas *limitaciones referenciales*; o sea, son un tamiz, una máscara, un colador. Las restricciones se utilizan para limitar el tipo de dato que puede recibir una columna de una tabla.

No tiene nada que ver con lo que **yo quiero tomar de una tabla**; más tiene que ver con lo que **yo permito poner en una tabla**. Y son esenciales en las relaciones para garantizar las mismas.

Yo creía que los foreign key condicionaban al sistema a entregar los datos de las tablas de cierta manera. Pero eso es un trabajo de los *select*.